# jquery mouseover image caption slideup

Tags: jquery, slideup

I'm trying to make images that when the user mouses over them, captions slide upward. I managed to get things working in a fashion using the hover function in JQuery but I want the caption to slide up from the bottom.

My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Gallery</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('figure.imgHolder img').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).next().slideUp(300);
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>

<figure class="imgHolder" id="batman">
    <img src="images/batman.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Batman</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="imgHolder" id="robin">
    <img src="images/robin.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Robin</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="imgHolder" id="superman">
    <img src="images/superman.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Superman</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="imgHolder" id="wonderwoman">
    <img src="images/wonderwoman.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Wonder Woman</figcaption>
</figure>


</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
.imgHolder {
    position: relative;
    width: 576px;
    height: 365px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.imgHolder img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.imgHolder figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 556px;
    padding: 10px;  
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if I understand you right.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('figure.imgHolder img').hover(function() {
                $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
            });
        });
```